# Refresh Captcha Image

Tags: php, javascript

How can I get the image source of the captcha image to refresh the captcha?

I am trying to do it like this but it's not working:

```
 <img id="captcha_img" src="<?php echo  CAPTCHA_PLUGIN_URL . "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&code=$code?>"?>" />


Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refresh_captcha();'>here</a> to refresh

<script type="text/javascript">
var refr_no = 0;
function refresh_captcha()
{
   var im = new Image();
   refr_no = refr_no + 1;
   im.src = "<?php echo  CAPTCHA_PLUGIN_URL . "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40"?>&refresh=" + refr_no;
   document.getElementById ("captcha_img").src = im.src;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code as well? You might need to add the `$code` too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create image object.

```
function refresh_captcha()
{
   im = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
   refr_no = refr_no + 1;
   im.src = "<?php echo  CAPTCHA_PLUGIN_URL . "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40"?>&refresh=" + refr_no;

}
```

Check out this demo: http://jsbin.com/ayenOce/2/edit

Comment: Actually image is not shown at the time i refresh it, it given an error like :    http://localhost:81/captcha/wp-content/plugins/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&refresh=1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @user2746038 Check out the demo regarded in the answer's edit. The problem now is related with the path of your captcha image. Try to find the correct path to your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refr_no = 0;
function refresh_captcha()
{
   refr_no = refr_no + 1;
   var oldSrc = document.getElementById("captcha_img").replace('&refresh='+(refr_no-1)+'','')+"&refresh="+refr_no;
   document.getElementById ("captcha_img").src = oldSrc;
   refr_no++;
}
</script>

<img id="captcha_img" src="<?php echo  CAPTCHA_PLUGIN_URL . "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&code=$code?>"?>" />


Can't read the image? click <a href='#' onclick="refresh_captcha(); return false;">here</a> to refresh
```

Comment: Actually it gives error as:      http://localhost:81/captcha/wp-content/plugins/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40 404 (Not Found)